# How Many Clients Could Not Send to Bech32 Addresses?

Tags: address, payment, bech32-address

For my client, I have set up a custom BTC payment solution using BTCPay Server.  The wallets I have configured in BTCPay Server produce only bech32 (`bc1xxx`) addresses for payments (cheapest transaction fees).

My client (who ordered the solution) has asked me how many of his customers would be *unable to send a payment to a bech32 address*?

**His concern is that his clients will be unable to pay their invoices in BTC because their wallets will be unable to send payments to the bech32 addresses.**

As I can see it, I can go back to my client with one of the following two answers:

1. Nearly all (`??%`) of wallets can send to bech32 including all\most commercial wallet providers so you don't need to worry, or
2. This is a problem and instead of bech32 addresses I need to set up a payment wallet that supports legacy addresses (either `1xxx` or `3xxx`).

**Could someone please tell me whether I can reassure him that the solution is fine as is, or whether I need to add legacy address support into it?**

Comment: Nearly all wallets can send to bech32 addresses. And you shouldn't be using wallets that lack good developers. My suggestions for bitcoin wallets: bitcoin core and electrum (desktop), samourai (android), green and fullynoded (iOS)

Comment: @Prayank Thanks for your comment. I'm not looking for a wallet provider or utilising one that has a problem sending to bech32.  My question is asking what proportion of the market is unavailable to me as a payment recipient if I only accept payment to bech32 addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer didn't appear to be forthcoming, I did my own research in order to address this question.

Based on the information provided by the [Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption) on Bech32 adoption, I surmised the following information.

1. All mainstream software wallets support *sending* to Bech32.
2. All mainstream hardware wallets support *sending* to Bech32 (either directly or via Electrum).
3. All major web wallets support *sending* to Bech32.
4. Most exchanges support *sending* to Bech32 (although notably Bitrex and LBC don't).

Note that I have specified *sending* because a lot of these do not support receiving funds via a Bech32 address as of yet.  However, for my particular requirement that is unimportant as it is about sending only.

With the above facts confirmed, the answer I actually gave to my client was:

**Nearly all wallets can send to bech32 including most commercial wallet providers so you don't need to worry.**

When he asked what percentage, I was unable to answer it.  I would need to know what percentage of daily volume went through the exchanges that didn't support Bech32.  However, given then pretty much every wallet does support it I felt that this was less relevant.

Comment: It's difficult to give a definitive answer on the percentage, since it is difficult to know which wallets are creating transactions in the first place. Another good resource is the Optech compatibility matrix: https://bitcoinops.org/en/compatibility/, however that was created in 2019, and I don't know if all of it is up to date.